# Error listas pygame python 3

Tags: python-3.x, lista, pygame

Tengo este codigo estoy construyendo un juego, pero me sale un error que al parecer es de las listas o arrays(no se es un poco ambiguo para mi).

ESte es el codigo:

```
import pygame
class Elemento(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, ruta):
        super().__init__()  
        image = pygame.image.load(ruta).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

class Pantalla():
    lista_elementos = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.lista_elementos = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Juego(Pantalla):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()         
        elementos = [[50, 50, "warzone.png"]
                     [600, 100, "cursor.png"]
                    ]
        for item in elementos:
            elemento = Elemento(item[0], item[1], item[2])
            self.lista_elementos.add(elemento)

def main():
    pygame.init()
    dimensiones = [700, 500]
    pantalla = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensiones)
    juego = Juego()
    hecho = False
    reloj = pygame.time.Clock()

    while not hecho:
        for evento in pygame.event.get():
            if evento.type == pygame.QUIT:
                hecho = True
        pantalla.fill(BLANCO)       
        juego.lista_elementos.draw(pantalla)
        pygame.display.flip()
        reloj.tick(60)
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Los archivos de imagenes estan guardados en la misma carpeta de donde esta el archivo .py.
Y este es el error

Despues de corregir la "," tuve una avalancha de errores que fui corrigiendo pero llegue a este, eh leido que es por el "pygame.init()" pero ahi esta, aunque no se si esta mal puesto.

Este es el error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manUel/Bttleshit/BttleShit.py", line 70, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/manUel/Bttleshit/BttleShit.py", line 56, in main
    for evento in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Antes de salir este error aparece por un momento la pantalla con todo lo que esperaba que apareciera. Pero despues de un instante se cierra dejando atras este error. :(

Fue una tonteria todo el tiempo el error era de identado con el pygame.quit que estaba dentro del ciclo while. Igual gracias por todo.

Comment: Error tipográfico en         `elementos = [[50, 50, "warzone.png"]
                     [600, 100, "cursor.png"]]`
                     en el inicializador de la clase `Juego`, te falta una coma, debe ser         `elementos = [[50, 50, "warzone.png"],
                     [600, 100, "cursor.png"]
                    ]`. Al faltar la coma interpreta que estás indizando `[50, 50, "warzone.png"]` con `600, 100, "cursor.png"` como índice, que no es un índice válido para una lista...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elementos = [[50, 50, "warzone.png"] [600, 100, "cursor.png"]]
```

debería ser

```
elementos = [[50, 50, "warzone.png"], [600, 100, "cursor.png"]]
```

te faltó una coma intermedia. Creo que es eso.